# Trying to make PHP check for duplicates in data insert

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, duplicates

`

```
mysql_connect("host","admin","password");//database connection

mysql_select_db("dbname");


$order="INSERT INTO members (username, password) VALUES ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";



$doopquery = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username='$_POST[username]' ")

if ($doopquery) {
    echo("Username Taken");
} else {
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    echo("Account Registered");
}
```

?>`

I have that so far  my db connection is fine, its when i get to the $doop

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this?  Can you include your error message and also your goal?

Comment: Just make username column unique in database, and catch errors

Comment: Daniel, as shown in the answers below, please make sure you sanitize any user input (e.g., by using mysql_real_escape_string) before putting the data into your query.  If you don't, you are subject to a simple but potentially very harmful SQL injection attack. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

```
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$doopquery = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username='$username' ");
if(mysql_num_rows($doopquery)==0){
     //username not found
}
else{
      //username already exists
 }
```

missing ' around username

missing ; at end of $doopquery

Comment: If username is Mike's Angel?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE username='{$username}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo "Username Already Taken!";
}else{
  $query = "INSERT INTO members (username, password) VALUES ('{$username}','{$password}')";
  if(mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "Account Registered!";
  }else{
    echo "Account Register Failed!";
  }
}
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What did you change? How does this solve the problem?